# MS EDGE BROWSER, After scrolling, Scroll event is fired again when pasting action

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I were searched this problem but seem like there is no information on the Google.
The problem is After Scrolling, Scroll event is fired again when pasting action

I've added Pasting & scroll event to check.
It works fine on Chrome Browser.

Reprocedure:

1. copy some text
2. scroll the div
3. Paste the text (ctrl+v) to any input (except the first or the last one)

note: This would not happen if scroll position is at top or bottom

[image]

please help

```js
let x = 0;
let scrollDiv = document.getElementById("scrollDiv");

function onScrollFunc(event) {
  console.log("Scrolling", event);
}
scrollDiv.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollFunc);

function onPaste(event) {
  console.log("PASTED", event);
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollDiv">
  In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
  <br><br>
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <input onPaste="onPaste(event)" /> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
</div>
```

Comment: Your example has missing functionality for `onPaste`  so you can't paste anything within div you added as content writer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in my EDGE 119.0.2151.72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with Edge 119.0.2151.72. Especially when I scroll a little (scroll minimun), then paste something, the issue will occur. When I scroll a lot, there won't be such issue.

I also test in Edge Canary 121.0.2235.0 and can't reproduce the issue. It means that the issue is fixed in future version of Edge stable. You can also [download Edge Canary](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/download/insider?form=MA13FJ) and have a test. We can also wait for the new release of Edge stable which will fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Appreciate it :)